# Python regex to match Ledger/hledger account journal entry

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a program in Python to parse a Ledger/hledger journal file.

I'm having problems coming up with a regex that I'm sure is quite simple. I want to parse a string of the form:

`expenses:food:food and wine            20.99`

and capture the account sections (between colons, allowing any spaces), regardless of the number of sub-accounts, and the total, in groups. There can be any number of spaces between the final character of the sub-account name and the price digits.

`expenses:food:wine:speciality       19.99` is also allowable (no space in sub-account).

So far I've got `(\S+):|(\S+ \S+):|(\S+ (?!\d))|(\d+.\d+)` which is not allowing for any number of sub-accounts and possible spaces. I don't think I want to have `OR` operators in there either as this is going to concatenated with other regexes with `.join()` as part of the parsing function.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
((?:[^\s:]+)(?:\:[^\s:]+)*)\s*(\d+\.\d+)
```

Now we can use:

```
s = 'expenses:food:wine:speciality       19.99'
rgx = re.compile(r'((?:[^\s:]+)(?:\:[^\s:]+)*)\s*(\d+\.\d+)')
mat = rgx.match(s)
if mat:
    categories,price = mat.groups()
    categories = categories.split(':')
```

Now `categories` will be a list containing the categories, and `price` a string with the price. For your sample input this gives:

```
>>> categories
['expenses', 'food', 'wine', 'speciality']
>>> price
'19.99'
```

Comment: Thank you. This may be the accepted answer, but I was hoping to see if it could be done without the subsequent `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for such a simple thing at all, native `str.split()` is more than enough:

```
def split_ledger(line):
    entries = line.split(":")  # first split all the entries
    last = entries.pop()  # take the last entry
    return entries + last.rsplit(" ", 1)  # split on last space and return all together

print(split_ledger("expenses:food:food and wine            20.99"))
# ['expenses', 'food', 'food and wine           ', '20.99']
print(split_ledger("expenses:food:wine:speciality       19.99"))
# ['expenses', 'food', 'wine', 'speciality      ', '19.99']
```

Or if you don't want the leading/trailing whitespace in any of the entries:

```
def split_ledger(line):
    entries = [e.strip() for e in line.split(":")]
    last = entries.pop()
    return entries + [e.strip() for e in last.rsplit(" ", 1)]

print(split_ledger("expenses:food:food and wine            20.99"))
# ['expenses', 'food', 'food and wine', '20.99']
print(split_ledger("expenses:food:wine:speciality       19.99"))
# ['expenses', 'food', 'wine', 'speciality', '19.99']
```

Comment: Thanks. Am aware that a simple `split()` would do the job, however I wish to use a regex as it's part of a larger regex-based parser. My question was really aimed at seeing if this could be done purely by a regular expression. Perhaps a mixture of the two as in answer @willemvanonsem is the only way.